# Kendo listview with many edit template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I use a kendo list view to show my records.

According to a field value, I would like use a different edit template on a field:

- if my field value type is a image, i would like show a kendo upload
- if my field value type is a text, i would like show a kendo editor

Is it possible ?
Do you have a sample ? a idea ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [template documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview), templates can have JavaScript code in them, including if/else blocks:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">
    #if(isAdmin){#
        <li>#: name # is Admin</li>
    #}else{#
        <li>#: name # is User</li>
    #}#
</script>
```

Just check your type in an if block and use whatever controls you need for that type.